# How can I refresh a dropdownlist during an event of another dropdownlist without refreshing whole web page?

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, autopostback, selectedindexchanged, page-refresh

I am developing my first asp.net website, my requirement  is to refresh  `DropDownListB`  at `SelectedIndexChanged` event of `DropDownListA`,  I have set `AutoPostBack="True"` for `DropDownListA`. Now the problem is whole web page gets refreshed, its unnecessary for me, is there any other technique that i can use to refresh only that control or only that panel rather than refreshing whole page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the dropdowns inside

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
// Dropdowns
</ContentTemplate> 
      </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and include `<asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>` at the top

Answer (score 2):

1- You can simply place the dropdown in an UpdatePanel, this will avoid a complete post back.

You can get more details on UpdatePanel [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx)

2- You can use jQuery `AJAX` to fetch the data in `JSON` format and bind it to the dropdown list, this approach is more efficient but little complex in comparison to `UpdatePanel`

You can find so many articles on this if you search this on google ,  [like](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/)

[EDIT]

You can find a similar implementation [here](http://www.joe-stevens.com/2010/02/23/populate-a-select-dropdown-list-using-jquery-and-ajax/)